# Create pattern condition dynamically

Tags: pattern-matching

Suppose i have a function

```
condition[pattern_,list_]:=With[
   {x=Unique["x"]},
   Condition[Pattern[Evaluate[x],pattern],Not@StringContainsQ[x,list]]
];
```

If i evaluate `condition[_,{"a","b","c"}]` i get an error.

But if i manually evaluate the right hand side i get the required result.

```
With[
   {x=Unique["x"]},
   Condition[Pattern[Evaluate[x],_],Not@StringContainsQ[x,{"a","b","c"}]]
]
```

result is

```
x56_ /; ! StringContainsQ[x56, {"a", "b", "c"}]
```

Comment: You could "isolate" `Condition` head by wrapping it with `Identity`: `condition[pattern_, list_] := With[{x = Unique@"x"}, Identity[Condition][x : pattern, Not@StringContainsQ[x, list]]]`.

Comment: In case of simple condition that just applies function to whole expression matched by pattern you could use `PatternTest` instead of `Condition`: `condition[pattern_, list_] := pattern?(Not@*StringContainsQ[list])`.

Answer (score 4):

From the help for `With`:

> You can use `With[{vars},body/;cond]` as the right-hand side of a transformation rule with a condition attached.

Basically, your code is that construction. Avoid having condition as the first head of the body of `With`:

```
condition[pattern_, list_] := 
  With[{x = Unique["x"]}, 
   Apply[Condition, {Pattern[x, pattern], 
     Not@StringContainsQ[x, list]}]];

condition[_, {"a", "b", "c"}]
(*x11_ /; ! StringContainsQ[x11, {"a", "b", "c"}]*)
```

Comment: You might want to prevent evaluation of `Condition` arguments by using holding wrapper instead of list: `Condition @@ Hold[x : pattern, Not@StringContainsQ[x, list]]`